# how to calculate checkbox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have checkbox with value, i want to calculate their value and show in alert box on click.

i tried it for last 2 hour but i cant understand how to make it possible

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){

    $('count').each(function(){



        })
    })
    })

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="5" />
<span>5</span>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="3" />
<span>3</span>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="10" />
<span>10</span>
</div>


<input type="button" value="calculate" />

</body>
```

Comment: What is meant by "i am not able to do it."? What do you observe?

Comment: we are here for learn if i am here it means i want to learn

Comment: The accepted answer works flawlessly! http://jsfiddle.net/BcqJu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this I hope it helps

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('button').click(function(){
             var total=0;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each( 
        function() { 
           total=total+parseInt($(this).val());

        } );
    alert(total);
        });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i just change  $('button') to  $(input[type=button]) and it is working checkout

Answer (score 2):

This is `HTML`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="5" />
<span>5</span>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="3" />
<span>3</span>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="10" />
<span>10</span>
</div> 
    <input id="example" type="button" value="calculate" />​
```

This is `Jquery`

```
function recalculate(){
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
      sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

    alert(sum);
}

$(function(){

    $('#example').click(function(){

        recalculate();

    });
});​
```

See this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/22/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() { // you can use id for the button
    $("input[name='count']").each(function() {
       total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    alert(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: i want to calculate their values like when we click on button the alert come with up 18

Comment: yes it is working but it is adding calculation in every click

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    result = 0;
    $('input[name=count]:checked').each(function(){
        result = Number(result) + Number($(this).val()); 
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click',function(){
    var tot=0;
    $("input[name=count]:checked").each(function() {
         tot += parseInt( $(this).prop('value'), 10 );
    });
    alert(tot);
});
```

### *[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5CPfu/2/)*

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.chkOptions').click(
    function () {
      var ntot = 0;
      $('.chkOptions:checked').each(function () {
        ntot += parseInt($(this).val());
      });
      $('#txtSavingsTot').val(ntot);
    })
  .change();
});
```